# Replace deprecated preg_replace /e with preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback, php-5.5

```
$result = preg_replace(
    "/\{([<>])([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)(\?{0,1})([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\}(.*)\{\\1\/\\2\}/iseU", 
    "CallFunction('\\1','\\2','\\3','\\4','\\5')",
    $result
);
```

The above code gives a deprecation warning after upgrading to PHP 5.5:

> **Deprecated**: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

How can I replace the code with `preg_replace_callback()`?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to pass the matches to your function:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback(
    "/\{([<>])([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)(\?{0,1})([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\}(.*)\{\\1\/\\2\}/isU",
    function($m) { return CallFunction($m[1], $m[2], $m[3], $m[4], $m[5]); },
    $result
);
```

Apart from being faster, this will also properly handle double quotes in your string. Your current code using `/e` would convert a double quote `"` into `\"`.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` should be shortened to `\w`, `{0,1}` to `?`, and the `i` pattern modifier serves to useful purpose.