# preg_replace deprecated use preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace, deprecated, preg-replace-callback

I am getting

> `preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead`

in one of the files in my application.

Near the below lines

```
   $str = preg_replace('/\&\#([0-9]+)\;/me', "code2utf('\\1',{$lo})",$str);
   $str = preg_replace('/\&\#x([0-9a-fA-F]+)\;/me', "codeHex2utf('\\1',{$lo})",$str);
```

How to convert the above `preg_replace` code to `preg_replace_callback`?

Answer (score -1):

Use [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Check this answer [Replace deprecated preg_replace /e with preg_replace_callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245205/replace-deprecated-preg-replace-e-with-preg-replace-callback)

Comment: I have written my above code as  $str = preg_replace_callback(
    "/\&\#([0-9]+)\;/me",
    function($m) { return code2utf($m[1],{$lo}); },
    $str
);

 $str = preg_replace_callback(
    "/\&\#x([0-9a-fA-F]+)\;/me",
    function($m) { return codeHex2utf($m[1],{$lo}); },
    $str
); I couldn't find deprecated issue but the page is blank. Is  this the way I have to use preg_replace_callback?

Comment: Post the full code block

Comment: I have created a test block for your reference just have a look https://ideone.com/k1xE5T