# Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated

Tags: javascript, php, error-handling

it tells me that I have to make the change here.

> Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in
>
> /var/home/cetemsco/public_html/Web/include/smarty/Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 270

```
$source_content = preg_replace_callback($search.'e', "'"
    . $this->_quote_replac                                                              
    ($this->left_delimiter) . 'php'
    . "' . str_repeat(\"\n\", substr_count('\\0', \"\n\")) .'"
    . $this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter)
    . "'"
    , $source_content);
```

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please include a title that describes your problem. Don't use anything like `could you please help me`

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this:

- [Replace deprecated preg_replace /e with preg_replace_callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245205/replace-deprecated-preg-replace-e-with-preg-replace-callback)

it will reffer you to:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php